# Reading spatial data from MSSQL changes format (order of X and Y coordinates reversed)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, spatial

We have a web app to show some spatial data on a map (.NET Core 3 MVC + EntityFramework). We store (spatial) data in MSSQL (`geometry` fields). In the code (c#) we use `NetTopologySuite.Geometries` to handle spatial types.

Now, when reading data from MSSQL table to a variable of type `LineString` or `Geometry` (NetTopologySuite.Geometries) the order of X and Y gets changed. For example:

in MSSQL we read a record with a Linestring that looks like this:

`LINESTRING (472414.67 84408.41, 472413.62 84408.54, 472410.94 84409.51, 472409.23 84410.81, 472407.87 84411.95)`

in c# it's stored to a `LineString` type (NetTopologySuite.Geometries), but it looks like this:

`LINESTRING(84408.41 472414.67,84408.54 472413.62,84409.51 472410.94,84410.81 472409.23,84411.95 472407.87)`

Original MSSQL geometry value (just in case, if it helps...): `0xD20E0000010405000000E17A14AE7AD51C41F6285C8F869BF440AE47E17A76D51C413D0AD7A3889BF440295C8FC26BD51C418FC2F528989BF440B81E85EB64D51C415C8FC2F5AC9BF440AE47E17A5FD51C4133333333BF9BF44001000000010000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000002`

Why is the order of X and Y different?

Comment: which SRS (Spatial Reference System) are you using?

Comment: We're using Srid 3794 on both DBs

Comment: No one? I find it hard to believe that we're the first to encounter this problem...